# Certain unicode characters unintentionally get converted to flag emoji in Android TextView

Tags: android, unicode, textview

I am trying to show a text in my android app using special unicode characters (Look like letters).

One character always is correspondending to tow unicode characters:
The first one is always '\uD83C' (55356) which is follwed by '\uDDF9' (56825) for 'A' for example (56826 for 'B' etc...). Setting the text generally works fine but whenever the text contains a substring which correpondens to a country encoding (Like 'ES' for Spain) it does not show the two characters but the flag instead.

I already tried to understand this behaviour and searched for possibilites to turn i did not find any soloutions

Example:

I want to show these characters:

String value as char array:
[image]

Result in my TextView:
[image]

Can you help me find a way to disable this behaviour. I already seen it working in other apps.

Comment: Note: unicode codes between D800 and DFFF are surrogates. So really not valid, but only used to encode unicode code point above 0xFFFF.  Your programming language may not know about UNICODE version 2 and later (1996), so it may use internally surrogates just as two unicode code point. Your operating system and fonts knows the surrogates, so they unite two codepoints to get the correct unicode, so the correct emoji

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characters you are using only exist to produce flag emoji; they serve no other purpose and are not intended to be used for “fancy” text. Displaying flags for valid region codes is their only correct behaviour.

If you absolutely have to use them without that happening, you need to insert invisible characters inbetween every letter to break up the ligatures, for example U+200C (Zero Width Non-Joiner) or U+2060 (Word Joiner).